# Can't download SUPEE-10570

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I've been having difficulties in downloading the patch. When I attempt to download the patch, I get prompted to login to MarketPlace. Then I get a form that asks about the site name, URL, and number of employees. After I click submit, I don't get anything and the form DOESN'T go away.

I've tried multiple browsers such as Chrome (the form doesn't change), and IE-Edge (after I click submit, I get the loading icon and that's it). I also used a different machine (Mac), I got the same result as on Chrome.

Any idea what's going on or how to get this patch downloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried and I'm able to download without any issue. 
I think you should try changing the IP. I used to have the same issue earlier but I tried changing the IP and it worked. It works fine now though. I mean no need to changing the IP.

And if you are still unable to download, you can try this blog post for Pre Patches Files: https://meetanshi.com/blog/install-magento-supee-10570-with-or-without-ssh/

You can also get the Patch Files from Brent Peterson's Repo for Every patches: https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches

Comment: Thanks @Gohil for your response. It's actually a bug in Magento's form that asks for information. I was able to solve the problem by accessing y account information, Profile, then I filled out the information missing such as URL, company name, income, role, etc.

Comment: The only issue I'm having now is that after installing the patch it still shows me that I'm at version 1.9.3.6!!!

Comment: @ASH Yes, Somewhere I read about that many other people were getting the same issue.

Comment: @ASH Installing Patch doesn't change your Magento Version. For that, you'll need to upgrade your Magento version. Installing a patch just fixes the vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you sure? The patch should change the version to 1.9.3.8. I checked the patches installed, and I was able to find the most recent patch installed. The issue is it didn't update the version from 1.9.3.6 to 1.9.3.8!

Comment: @ASH Yes, I'm 100% sure that installing the patch doesn't update the Magento Version.